# PHP - Временные image-файлы, удаляемые после передачи на клиента

Tags: php

PHP-скрипт формирует для клиента HTML-страницу и набор отображаемых этой страницей image-файлов. После отображения image-файлов на клиенте они должны быть удалены (на сервере). Image-файлы представляют собой картинки размером примерно 200Х300.

На вскидку видится три способа осуществления этого:

1. В обработчик onload HTML-страницы добавить вызов в другом фрейме скрипта очистки
2. Поставить на крон периодическую процедуру сбора мусора
3. В PHP-скрипте форкать через system или exec параллельный процесс, который по заданной паузе почистит мусор.
   Но как-то это все... вельми кучеряво.

А нет ли возможности получить от Apache сигнал о завершении обмена с клиентом по данному скрипту и обработать его?
Или указать Apache, что некоторые файлы можно удалить после завершения обмена?

Comment: Зачем тогда физически создавать эти картинки? Генерите content-type: image/png прямо скриптом

Comment: @toxxxa А верстку как в таком случае делать? Можно "рамочный" пример, скажем, для двух картинок? Извините мою возможную дремучесть.

Comment: Какая задача конкретно перед вами стоит?

Comment: @Naumov
Картинки содержат конфиденциальную информацию и хранятся на сервере в зашифрованном виде. Перед отдачей на клиента создается расшифрованная копия и ее надо побыстрее удалить. Понятно, что крипто-апплет с расшифровыванием на клиенте был бы идеальным решением, но... это совсем другие трудозатраты, скажем так.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можете сделать страницу (назовем ее image.php и она будет в корне) которая будет отдавать такие картинки и сразу удалять.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$name = "/path/to/dir/".$_GET['name'];
if(is_file($name)){
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($name);
    if($im!==false){    
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
        unlink($name);
        }
    }
```

В самой верстке у картинок `src` указывать http://example.com/image.php?name=picture.png. Это пример, дальше можете сделать имя картинки числовым и передавать только номер картинки через `$_GET` без формата и проверять правильность имени.

Answer (score 1):

Сам так не делал, поэтому в основном теория, пусть старшие товарищи меня поправят:

сделать через .htaccess переадресацию, чтоб вместо загрузки картинок запрос отправлялся в скрипт:

```
RewriteRule ^img/(.*\.jpg?)$ /image.php?file=$1 [L,R=301]
```

сам скрипт будет выдавать заголовок и содержимое картинки:

```
echo "Content-Type: image/png\n";
echo image_uncrypt($filename);
```